Fast way to compare a large set of positions, rotations, velocities, etc. during runtime (possibly every frame)
The Goal
I'm working on a vr gesture recognition system. Normally these systems are dependent on "drawn" gestures, but I want something that compares position, rotation, velocity, angular velocity, etc. based on user determined "thresholds".
My Current Solution
The main method I've explored is fast. I use spatial hashing to create a grid space around the player and find which grid cell the object, or hands in this case, are in.
Users can record these gestures in the editor. Then when loading the game, these recorded gestures can be scaled according to player sizes and other specifications, then stored in a hash table.
While I haven't implemented it yet, I plan to be able to allow storage of a gesture in a neighboring cell if it's within a radius tolerance of the recorded position.
This works quite fast. Even with a quickly thrown together Unreal Blueprints implementation, ticking on every frame, I didn't notice more than an average of 5 fps drop (at around 140 fps). Keep in mind this was also drawing debug squares for the cell each hand is reading from. The grid size was 40 * 40 * 40 for a total of 64,000 grid squares.
Of course I am aware that this type of thing should be done on a timer rather than in a frame tick, but I want it to be a plausible option.
The Problem
The current solution works great for positions, but I'm uncertain as to how well it will work on rotation and velocity. At first I thought I would just make position a requirement, then once the best gesture has been decided, see if the other values work well enough.
But what if a user wants to capture purely a flicking motion in any arbitrary direction? Or a rotation and angular velocity at any arbitrary location?
I thought then, that velocity and rotation and everything are all just 3d vectors, so maybe they could be hashed the same way. The rotation may not be so troublesome. I just have to convert any rotations axis to be from 0 - 360 degrees. But velocity may be a little more troublesome if the player is capable of producing extreme values that are out of the range of the grid, since the grid is a fixed size.
Plus, the performance impact may actually start to be a problem if I'm calculating 3 or 4 different keys every frame. And of course I'd have to triple or quadruple the amount of for loops that check between each gesture stored in these cells.
The Question(s)
Is there a better way of filtering these other values? Or a better way to compare all values including position quickly and efficiently every frame? Or is such a thing completely out of my scope?
Thank you for reading this far into the post, and any help or insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated

Attributes like rotation, velocity, angular velocity, etc. are no different than position. They are all dimensions that describe the state of a gesture. The goal is to try to match the preset gestures with the current gesture every frame. So the algorithms I recommend here are Dimensionality_reduction and Nearest_neighbor_search. They preprocess the data to make the comparison process faster.

It sounds like you're doing a lot of scanning; even on things that are not moving (apparently). A non-moving item needs to be scanned only once; if it's a target.

Actually, if using euler angles on a rotation, wouldn't this cause issues with gimble locking? I imagine doing the same thing with quaternions would be a fair bit more complicated. If I'm making a key from a position, I'm getting converting its position into coordinates by dividing an axis value by its corresponding grid axis size, and flooring it. How will that work on quaternions?
